# How to propper pre-build Shopware inside a pipeline

Tags: continuous-integration

I'm looking for good practice on how to build a shopware system properly inside an pipeline. Performing composer install, build-js.sh etc. on the target system takes some time and I'd like to pre-build it and deploy only the artefacts. I was trying to achive this by using bin/console theme:dump and bin/ci bundle:dump by following bin/build-administration.sh etc. from [dcoumentation](https://developer.shopware.com/docs/guides/hosting/installation-updates/deployments/build-w-o-db.html) but ended up in somehow incomplete bundles.